# C++ Converting Different Types to String Temporarily

Tags: c++, string, getline

I apologise if this question is a bit long winded. I will try to keep it short but concise.

I am building a major program for an entry level C++ course, where I am creating a mock version of employee management for a warehouse. The general form is that the user is asked for input in order to select the type of employee, and then, based on the input, is then asked to input the employee details relevant to that employee type.

Due to this, there are functions that accept input as int, float, string and char. I have a separate smaller function that checks for 'exit' as input, and exits the program if this is true. I currently have this designed so that all inputs are classed as strings, but this obviously causes problems later when I try to equate values numerically.

Here is my current version of the check function and one of the user input functions:

```
//Current add_employee function
void add_employee()
{
        string emp_type = "";
        bool exit_check;
        cout << "Please select employee type. Enter 1 for Manager or 2 for Dockhand." << endl;
        getline(cin, emp_type);
        if(name.empty())
        {
                cout << "Cannot accept empty field as input. Please answer with 1 for Manager, or 2 for Dockhand." << endl;
                add_employee();
        }
        exit_check = check_input(emp_type);
        if(exit_check == true)
        {
                return;
        }
        if(emp_type == "1")
        {
                add_manager;
        }
        else if(emp_type == "2")
        {
                add_dockhand;
        }
        else
        {
                cout << "Sorry. Your input is invalid. Please answer with 1 for Manager, or 2 for Dockhand." << endl;
                add_employee();
        }
}

//Current check function
bool check_input(string input_var)
{
        if(input_var == "exit")
        {
                return true;
        }
        else
        {
                return false;
        }
}
```

As for my question. Is there a relatively simple way to keep the structure of my code, taking the input as an int, then converting it to a string to check for 'exit', but also having the input still being considered an int if the exit_check is false? I was thinking about having the input assigned to two variables, but that felt like a waste of code.

Please let me know if something does make sense and I will edit it into the OP.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by that? There's far more than just this to the entire program, but there was no point copying all of it into the question when two functions is enough to show what I mean.

Comment: Why do you want to use a string to check the employee type? You can directly compare int types and assign a particular integer for exit.

Comment: @Raul That's what my original design was, but then I wasn't able to get the check_input function to check for 'exit' being input. I was trying to have it set up so the check_input function can be used after each input stage so I didn't have to copy the code in each time. Not all of the user inputs are going to be of the same type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getline(cin, emp_type); is going to grab a string from the user. You're not getting an int as an input anywhere in that code.

You could simplify this by changing:

```
 exit_check = check_input(emp_type);
        if(exit_check == true)
        {
                return;
        }
```

to

```
if(emp_type.compare("exit") == 0)
            {
                    return;
            }
```

which checks if the strings are equal. (See [compare()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/) for the details on that operator.) and removing the check_input function.

If you need an int from the input then [zenith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3425536/zenith) pretty much covered how to do that.

Comment: So I would basically be accepting all input as strings, comparing them to exit, checking for an empty field with if(name.empty()), and then converting the input to an int afterwards? Just checking if I understand the process. Is it possible to convert strings to char or float as well? I'd have to do the same process inside other functions that require those types.

Comment: Or even simpler: `emp_type == "exit"` instead of `emp_type.compare("exit") == 0`.

Comment: @DwayneH Yes, why not. `input.at(0)` will get the first char, and there's [`std::stof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) for float conversion. Remember that a user input is always a string, and only by parsing that string you can get the numerical values that are represented in this textual format.

Comment: @zenith That's perfect. Many thanks to you both. I might still keep the exit check as a separate small function just so I don't have to have the same thing written in every time, as there's a potential for large quantities of user input.

Answer (score 0):

> taking the input as an int, then converting it to a string to check for 'exit'

That's impossible. If you read the input into an int, any non-numerical input will fail, and you will not be able to check for the string 'exit'.

What you could do is take the input as a string to a variable, say `input`, and then convert it to int with `stoi`:

```
int emp_type = std::stoi(input);
```

---

As an aside, you might want to take the parameter of `check_input` by reference, to avoid making a copy of the entire string every time the function is called:

```
bool check_input(string const& input_var)
```